# Redirecting URL in JBOSS AS 7

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, url-rewriting, query-string, jboss7.x

Hi everyone currently i am passing query string in my url like

```
ip:port/contextroot/page.jsf?id=22&tsid=1234
```

the query string is a user id and tsid. the doesnt specifically need to type in the query string values. my requirement is to hide the query string in the url and still be able to use the query string values in my app. i was thinking if there is a way to strip off the query string using jboss redirection.

To Summarize:

i wanna access my page.jsf like

```
 ip:port/contextroot/page.jsf
```

and still get id and tsid  from the query string.
any help is geartly appreciated.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Showing a user id to everyone in a GET param looks dangerous to me - what it people change its value? Maybe these params were better stored in the user's session, thus you would not need them appended to each URL.

Comment: yes exactly, it is pretty dangerous, thats the reason i wanna hide. i basically have a dot net application where a user clicks on a link and he'd be redirected to a java app. now the users session params are in dot net world, the only way i could pass these info is using html through querystring to my java world.

Comment: Then you should encrypt all sensible data (using a symmetric cipher) to be transmitted to your Java application. POST instead of GET will look nicer for the user. I would rather submit to a servlet which decrypts to data and stores them in a (newly created) session for the user.

Comment: @f_puras sounds thats the only way to do it. i was just wondering if there was a way to hide the query string and still be able to use the values in my managed bean ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your .NET application, encrypt all sensible data using a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES), then POST it to a JBOSS servlet. In that servlet, decrypt the transmitted data and store it in a session scoped bean. This way, you can subsequently access the data from your beans without needing to carry it aound in GET params.

Comment: i think i would go with your suggestion .. thanks a lot .. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck! I can imagine the en-/decrypting between both systems becoming a bit fiddly...

Comment: i dint use any encryption/decryption algorithm .. i just used ROT47.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Pretty Faces ( http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ )

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .. but i will go with f_puras suggestion :)